# Create role with permissions on SSAS using PowerShell

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell, ssas

In SQL Server SSAS I want to do a db restore from server A to server B, where DB already exists on server B. I was wondering if it's possible to script database permissions, so I can later run the script on server B to apply the original settings.

I was playing around with AMO, but I have limited programming knowledge, so not entirely sure how it works.

I know I can access this information:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.AnalysisServices”)
$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$SSASServerName = 'serverNameA\PRD'
$SSASServer.Connect($SSASServerName)
$SSASServer.Version

$DBName = 'DB_A_PRD'
$SSASDatabase = $SSASServer.Databases.Item($DBName)
$SSASDatabase.Refresh()
```

so later I can get all details about specific role

```
foreach ($role in $SSASDatabase.Roles) {Write-Host $role.Name}
$SSASDatabase.DatabasePermissions.FindByRole($role.ID)
```

Now I can recreate role on the server B

```
$roleToCreate = new-Object([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role])($var)
$SSASDatabase.Roles.Add($roleToCreate)
$roleToCreate.Update()
```

And here's where I am lost. How should I properly assign Administer, or Process permissions to this $roleToCreate?

I've seen another user who applied Read settings this way, but I did not find way do to the same for Administer or Process permissions:

```
$dbperm = $SSASDatabase.DatabasePermissions.Add($roleToCreate.ID)    
$dbperm.Read = [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ReadAccess]::Allowed
```

From what I've read here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/amo/programming-amo-security-objects?view=sql-analysis-services-2022 it is possible, but I am not sure how to make it work in PowerShell.

I cannot do it as $dbpermissions.Process = True, ps won't recognize it.
I imagine I need to do something similar as with enums with Read rights, but I don't know how.

I was using this documentation for refrence:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices?view=analysisservices-dotnet

Comment: Try `$dbperm.Process = $true` - in PowerShell, the Boolean constants are `$true` and `$false`.

Comment: As an aside: the proper syntax for your second `New-Object` call is: `New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role -ArgumentList $var` (you may omit `-ArgumentList`); alternatively, using method syntax in PSv5+: `[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role]::new($var)`

Comment: @mklement0 It does seem like that was it. After I ran refresh, change was there both in GUI and Powershell. It's long road ahead of me I guess haha
Thanks for the tip as well, can you recommend any resource where I could learn about how to use these?

Comment: Glad to hear it; do you mean learning about constants such as `$true`? Technically, they are called _automatic variables_: see [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty adding roles with `$SSASDatabase.Roles.Add($roleToCreate)`. It would log a 0 to the terminal, indicating that nothing had been added.

I decided to move on and found a different approach with TMSL. This solution creates a new role, but you can also amend it to createOrReplace.

```
$tabularName = "tableName"
$sqlServer = "ssasServer"

$json = @"
{   
    "create":{   
       "parentObject":{   
          "database":"$($tabularName)"  
       },  
       "role":{  
          "name":"NewRoleName",  
          "modelPermission":"read",
          "members":[   
             {  
                "memberName": "domain\\username"
             }
          ]
       }  
    }  
 }
"@

$connectionString = "Data Source=$sqlServer;Initial Catalog=$tabularName"
Invoke-ASCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $json
```

**Useful docs**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/roles-object-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/createorreplace-command-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions